# What encoding is this '\x00\x00\x00\x05'?

Tags: java, python, sockets, encoding, tcp

I'm sending an Integer from my Java Client to my Python Server using:

```
outputStream.writeInt(5);
```

And on the server:

```
_id = self.request.recv(4)
```

I get:

```
Name   | Type|  Value
_id    | str |  '\x00\x00\x00\x05'
```

How can i decode this and convert it back to Integer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can decode this with the python [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>i', '\x00\x00\x00\x05')
(5,)
```

The `>i` pattern expects a big-endian signed integer (4 bytes).

Comment: Works great! Where can i read more about the first argument of unpack?
how to decide the format? I need to unpack a 32 byte string..

Comment: @Danpe: It's in the [documentation of the module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

Comment: checksum = struct.unpack('>32s', self.request.recv(32))[0]
**error: unpack requires a string argument of length 32**

Comment: @Danpe: I suspect `self.request.recv(32)` didn't receive 32 bytes. Network and file read operations *can* return fewer bytes than requested..